# Use ng-click to filter blog posts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building a blog using AngularJS and JSON. Everything is working except for one filter item. I am fairly new to Angular and am struggling with it.

I have an unordered list of tags that I am printing out using ng-repeat like so:

```
<li class="tag" ng-repeat="myScope.myJsonTag">{{tag}}</li>
```

and I would like to add ng-click to it in order to filter blog post previews whose content is filtered in via Angular using the same JSON file and the same scope that I am getting the data for the tags from.

I am pulling the very same tags into my blog posts like so (please disregard the search..I have an Angular live search already working.):

```
<div class="blog_item" ng-repeat="d in blogData | filter:filters"
     ng-show="([d.header.title, d.content] | filter:filterBySearch).length > 0, d.d.header.taxonomy.tag.join('') | ">
    <div class="top_img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
    </div>

    <div class="item_text">
        <h3>{[{d.header.title}]}</h3>
        <p>{[{d.content.trunc(100)}]}</p>
        <a ng-href="insights/{[{d.header.title | slugify}]}">Read Article</a>
        <p class="tag">{[{d.header.taxonomy.tag.join('')}]}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just not fully understanding how I can add the click event to the list item and have it filter only the blog posts with matching tags. I feel like I have tried everything, but this does not feel like something that should be all that difficult.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the filters you are already using?

Comment: One of them is for the live search and the other is to take the post title, make it lowercase, and connect it with a - for the post URL.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to set a selectedTag variable on click and then you can use this selectedTag variable to filter the posts:

```
<li class="tag" ng-repeat="myScope.myJsonTag" ng-click="selectedTag=tag">{{tag}}</li>
```

or you can watch for change in selectedTag and filter:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedTag', function(tag) {
    // filter posts here
})
```

Another way is to send the tag to the controller and make the filtering happen at the controller:

```
<li class="tag" ng-repeat="myScope.myJsonTag" ng-click="filterByTag(tag)">{{tag}}</li>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.filterByTag = function(tag) {
    // you can filter post by tags
};
```

Comment: This part makes sense to me, and I have tried it, but the thing I am not following is how to connect it to the blog posts (as posted above). How do I make it so when the list item is clicked it shows only blog posts with that specific tag?

Comment: Do you have an API that can filter posts by tag?

Comment: I do not; though I am not sure that would be needed there. The posts are already being printed and the all contain the tag on the post. If you look at the 'item_text' div you will see that there. I am just trying to write script that matches the list item clicked in the separate navigation; with the matching links in the posts. If the tags in the posts do not match I would like to hide them.